# dont allow using pwa offilne in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA application with PWA and the service worker.

My application allows to use the app when user is offline.

but I want to not to allow access to user when the app is offline.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add listener for online/offline.

```
  var networkFlag = true;
  window.addEventListener('online', handleConnection);
  window.addEventListener('offline', handleConnection);
```

Inside HandleConnection you can set flag variable true or false based on network is online or offline. Using this flag variable you restrict loading your pages in offline.

```
  function handleConnection() {
   networkFlag = navigator.onLine;
    }
```

Hope this helps your case.

Comment: where i can put it ???

Comment: if can do this i can use the pwa option for install it in the smaprt phone ?

Comment: I was wrong you can do Online/Offline check in DOM JS only.  Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events). May be based on this event you can force the user to offline page.